# Coverting string value to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe which has a column containing date-time values as object datatype.

```
    col1    col2            col3
0    A       10     2016-06-05 11:00:00
0    B       11     2016-06-04 00:00:00
0    C       12     2016-06-02 05:00:00
0    D       13     2016-06-03 02:00:00
```

What Im trying to do is convert the col3 into date-time values so that it would just give me:

```
 Year-Month-Day-Hour
```

For some datetime feature engineering later on. When I try:

```
df['col3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col3'])
```

I get this error:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3008-07-25 00:00:00
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use parameter `errors='coerce'` for convert values outside limits to `NaT`:

```
print (df)
  col1  col2                 col3
0    A    10  2016-06-05 11:00:00
0    B    11  2016-06-04 00:00:00
0    C    12  2016-06-02 05:00:00
0    D    13  3008-07-25 00:00:00
```

---

```
df['col3'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col3'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
  col1  col2                col3
0    A    10 2016-06-05 11:00:00
0    B    11 2016-06-04 00:00:00
0    C    12 2016-06-02 05:00:00
0    D    13                 NaT
```

[Timestamp limitation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations):

```
In [68]: pd.Timestamp.min
Out[68]: Timestamp('1677-09-21 00:12:43.145225')

In [69]: pd.Timestamp.max
Out[69]: Timestamp('2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775807')
```

Also is possible create [Periods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#representing-out-of-bounds-spans), but not easy from strings:

```
def conv(x):
    return pd.Period(year = int(x[:4]), 
                     month = int(x[5:7]), 
                     day = int(x[8:10]),
                     hour = int(x[11:13]), freq='H')

df['col3'] = df['col3'].apply(conv)

print (df)
  col1  col2             col3
0    A    10 2016-06-05 11:00
0    B    11 2016-06-04 00:00
0    C    12 2016-06-02 05:00
0    D    13 3008-07-25 00:00
```